# Difference between Avro serialization and Avro format

Tags: hadoop, serialization, format, avro

I am reading a book Hadoop application architectures, which is quite old but very interesting, and while reading, I have remarked that Avro is considered as data serialization framework, compared to Parquet, which is considered as columnar data format.

- Could we say that Avro is a row-oriented data format ?
- What is a difference between Avro serialization framework and Avro format ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization is the process on taking data *into a format*.

Avro files are stored in the *Avro format*, which is row oriented, yes

What might make Avro a framework is that it has a protocol (RPC) and a format